# Magento2: Question about product scope & language

Tags: magento2, product, language, scope

I understand you can have a website, with a store which will contain multiple storeviews. So in example the default storeview is in English and a second storeview is in German with domain (website.de). You translate the products to German within the German storeview scope.

At some point you also create a few extra German storeviews so you can also have domains like website.at and website.ch. However when you create those storeviews the following problem arises:

For the products in now falls back on the default language (english).

1. Is there a way to let these new storeviews use the german product descriptions? Or do I have to go through the entire catalog for both storeviews and copy paste the german descriptions?
2. What is the proper way to set this up? It seems creating a german store of website even does not do the trick. Within a product I can only switch scopes between 'All Store Views' and a specific storeview.

Thank you for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new store view it will automatically inherit the translations from the website under which it is created.

Even if you would set up a German website it will not help you much as the store switcher in the catalog is on store view (as you write). So you will not be able to set the website values on the German store view and have them inherit, you will be stuck with the English values.

Best approach is probably to have one English website and when you create the second german store view, you use Magentos import / export functionality. You export all product description for the German store into csv and change the store view name and import them to the other german store.